# Labeling KPCA in R

Tags: r, pca, rbf-kernel

The function $\texttt{biplot}$ in R is very useful for creating visualizations when performing PCA.  However, when performing kernel PCA in R, I cannot find a way to label the loadings on the graph.  Here is an example below.

[image]

The loading vectors are clearly labeld.  In KPCA, I get an output that looks something like this.

[image]

As you can see, there are no labels whatsoever on the graph.  Is there a way to add labels?  I am using $\texttt{plot(kpc@pvc)}$ to plot the data.

Thanks!